# How to remove letters and space from line in python?

Tags: python, line

Im new in python and I have problem like this:

I have a list

```
Index = ['TH', '1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2', '']
```

and I wat to get

```
max(Index)
```

I have something like this sofar

```
import numbers
Index = ['TH', '1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2', '']
Index1 = [x for x in Index if x] #to remove empty space
Index2 = [x for x in Index1 if isinstance(x, numbers.Number)] #to remove all letters
Index3 = map(int, Index2)
print (max(Index3))
```

But output from Index1 and Index2 is always [].

Comment: What is the actual problem statement here?

Comment: When I run the code I see that `Index1` has a number of values in it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you meant to use the `isdigit()` method of strings:

```py
Index = ['TH', '1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2', '']
Index1 = [x for x in Index if x] #to remove empty space
Index2 = [x for x in Index1 if x.isdigit()] #to remove all letters
Index3 = map(int, Index2)
print (max(Index3))
```

Output:

```
29
```

Comment: The first iteration is not needed as the empties are filtered  out by isdigit also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Index = ['TH', '1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2', '']
my_index = [int(elem) for elem in Index if elem.isnumeric()]
```

Comment: You must to has integers, if there can come float numbers, you must to use the statement  <isinstance>

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66707386/edit) your post to add more details and explanations. Don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Index = ['TH', '1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2', '']
print(max(map(int,filter(str.isdigit,Index))))
```

Filter out anything not a digit,
`filter(str.isdigit,Index)`

then map all to integers,
`map(int,)`

Then get the max.
`max()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Index = ['TH', '1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2', '']
result = [i for i in Index if not(not i or i.isalpha())]
print(result)
```

> Output:- ['1', '1', '2', '28', '29', '2']